# Why was Chinese chosen as the written language in "The Last Airbender"?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Does anyone know why Chinese (instead of, for example Japanese) was chosen as the written language in *The Last Airbender*?

[image: water bender calligraphy]

[image: Aang's wanted poster]

Comment: Could you add some elaboration about the signs, etc., as you did in chat? Otherwise the phrase “second language” might be confusing.

Comment: I don't think it was the second language. I think it's supposed to be the language of the Avatar world and English is just a "translation".

Comment: @svick I would agree with you except if you watch Anime(correct me if I am wrong) they often display English words in the videos while it my opinion it isn't implied that the real language is in english.  Also there are very few chinese speaking places in the world even if this is a make believe tv show.

Comment: +1 because I just checked Wikipedia, and it seems like [China had a different version of the elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element#China), featuring wood and metal but not air. The four elements from the show seem to match Buddhism though.

Comment: What do you mean when you say there are very few Chinese-speaking places in the world? I mean, China is the main one, but it has 1 billion people and quite a lot of surface area. And then there’s Hong Kong, Macau, Taiwan, and Singapore. Perhaps not as many separate states as English or Arabic or Spanish, but not really obscure either. ;) If the comparison is meant to be to Japanese, it’s official only in Japan. It’s actually rather isolated, comparatively–no surprise, when we consider the etymology of the word “isolated”!

Comment: @Adamant I meant with Caucasian people yes not clear.  The characters in both the tv show and movie are in my opinion obviously Caucasian.  China has small groups of Cuacasian people but not many I have gathered.

Comment: @William - I don't know about the film, but in the TV series many characters did not appear Caucasian to me. The anime style can obscure things sometimes, but nonetheless.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh The East Asian 5 elements are pretty interesting when you stat looking at the dozens of things they are metaphors for and how that all ties into the tai chi or bagua. But the 4 Indian elements (the culture from which Buddhism derives its ideas) are the same as the Western four except that their fifth element (quintessence) is space/void. The four elements would be "energy" in that space, so there was no "energy element."

Answer (score 21):

The creators talk about the show's behind-the-scenes at length in *Avatar: The Last Airbender - The Art of the Animated Series* (2010). They did specifically set on Chinese as the written language; and that ties in with them drawing so heavily from other Chinese mythology, arts and folklore that using another calligraphy would just have looked out of place. It provides information on the "but, Chinese elements usually have metal and wood as well" issue raised in the comments.

[Page 26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdVPL.jpg):

> DEVELOPING THE ART OF BENDING
>
> BRYAN: We had a desire to do something physical and tangible with the concept of magic, something more dynamic than the usual “magic wand” fare. **As we settled into the concept of an Asian-influenced fantasy world, the idea of using traditional Chinese martial arts to manipulate the elements was the next logical step.** Films like *Shaolin Soccer* helped to influence this idea, building on a tradition in Hong Kong cinema of blending supernatural powers with kung fu. Our bending concept allowed for high-energy action scenes without an emphasis on violence, since the practitioners are generally fighting element to element rather than fist on face.
>
> People often assume the “four-element theory” (comprised of air, water, earth, and fire) we brought to bending is exclusive to ancient Greece, and that in ancient China only a “five-element theory” was used (comprised of wood, fire, earth, metal, and water). Mike and I never claim to be experts in any of these subjects, but in our research we found the four-element theory was prevalent in ancient cultures all over the world, including ancient Buddhist teachings. While the five-element theory is interesting in its own right, we were attracted to the universality of the four simple elements. It makes for an instantly understandable concept that has translated well to audiences in a number of disparate cultures, just like it did thousands of years ago.

[image: hand-drawn sketches of bending movements]

Pages 126 to 130 are a spotlight on the show's calligraphy.

> SPOTLIGHT: The Calligraphy of S. L. Lee
>
> BRYAN: **We decided early on that we would use Chinese for all writing and signage seen within the show. Much in the way Sifu Kisu became the martial-arts consultant, we wanted to find a Chinese calligraphy expert to handle all of the writing.** An Internet search led us to the work of Dr. Siu-Leung Lee (known to us as S. L. Lee). I e-mailed him and heard back within the hour, and we have been working together ever since.
>
> S. L. Lee handled all of the translation and calligraphy for *Avatar*, including providing the calligraphy for our logo. His vast knowledge and command of various styles of calligraphy throughout China’s history added a culturally grounding component to the show.
>
> When I would send Dr. Lee a request for a poster or a decree, he would quiz me about what unseen fictional character had done the calligraphy in the show. If it were a highly cultured royal attendant, he would use a refined, elegant style, but if it were a low-level clerk, he would use a more pedestrian handwriting style. We typically used classical Chinese for the writing, but thanks to Dr. Lee’s deep knowledge, we also included archaic Chinese, particularly for ancient texts about the spirits or elements. We were truly lucky to have such a great talent contributing his beautiful work and expertise to our show.

[image: full text with various calligraphy illustrations, including wanted posters]

Answer (score -1):

Avatar is set in an ancient East Asia - like place. In those thousands of years of time, written Japanese did not exist. To summarize, the Chinese written language had significant influence on the writing systems of East Asian countries.

For most of history, Japan as well as Korea didn't have their own writing system and their languages only existed as oral languages. 3000 years after the Chinese developed a writing system, the Yamato clan in 5th century (year 400 - 500 AD) adopted Chinese characters as their writing system.  That is why 60% of modern Japanese is Kanji, which are Chinese loan words written in Chinese characters.

Before the development indigenous writing systems like Hiragana in Japan and Hangul in Korea, Chinese characters were the medium for writing in both countries so the vast majority of ancient scrolls and history texts are written in Chinese.

Comment: While Kanji characters are taken from Chinese, the meanings are not exactly the same; it's like saying that because English uses characters derived from Latin, something written in Latin is actually written in English.

Comment: By your own admission, 40% of Japanese characters are not Chinese in origin, which would mean that the two written languages are not the same overall, despite plenty of overlap. Which brings us back to the question of why the creators of _The Last Airbender_ chose to go with Chinese rather than Japanese, or some other language for that matter.

Comment: Like I stated above, Avatar world takes place in an ancient east asia like place, which is why Chinese would make more sense as the written language. Because Hiragana didn't exist at the time. Watch any historical / period Korean drama which is pretty popular these days on netflix. They all write in Chinese characters. If Avatar was set in ancient Rome then it would make sense for scrolls to be written in Latin instead of English. To give viewers an immersive experience.

Answer (score -3):

The different types of bending are based on different types of Chinese martial arts. Water bending is based on Tai Chi, Fire bending is based on Northern Shaolin, Earth bending is based on Hung Ga, and Air bending is based on Bagua Zhang (pronounced "bag waa"). So Chinese writing is used because the central thematic element of the show (bending) is based on Chinese martial arts.

Comment: I think you might be looking at the tail wagging the dog. They chose Chinese martial arts to represent the bending elements because the theme is faux-Chinese rather than the other way around.

Comment: Your suggestion that I may have been looking at the tail wagging the dog (I do love that expression) is conjecture.  It may very well be the case that the martial arts were Chinese because the theme was faux-Chinese, but it may also be the case that the theme was faux-Chinese because the martial arts they chose were Chinese.  Both options have their potential merit.

Comment: Providing some evidence that I'm wrong would be an excellent way to improve this answer. I'd turn my frown upside-down and change my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: If I were you I would keep that downvote a downvote.  I just re-checked the documentary on the ATLA series (Avatar Spirits) and the creators stated that they were heavily influenced by Anime (specifically Gainax and studio Gibbly) and Kung Fu movies.  My first interpretation was that they drew inspiration from Kung Fu movies, chose all Chinese martial arts, thus chose a faux-Chinese theme.  But after reading your comment, I realize that it is more likely that their inspiration led to them choosing a faux-Chinese theme.  Thanks for keeping me honest Valorum.